# setting up header react native

Tags: android, react-native, header, react-router

I'm working on `react native`. This is my first day. I want to design the header. I have added the header in **app.js** file like this.

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Header headerText="About us"/>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
  </View>
  </View>
);
 }
```

---

And I have made a sperate class header.js file like this:

---

```
const Header = (props) => {
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
        <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
        <Image source={require('./image.png')} style={{height:24, width:24}}/>
        </View>
        );
};

const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#a01b1b',
        height: 66,
        justifyContent: 'center',

        alignItems:'center',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.9,
        elevation: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 25 : 0,
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,

        padding:10
    },

};
```

But i'm not getting header.

Answer (score 0):

Import the `header.js` at the top of the `app.js` file.

```
import Header from './header';
```

> Add the correct path to `'./header'` in above import.

Export the 'header.js' file at the bottom of `header.js`.

```
export default header;
```

Comment: yes i have already did this in app.js as well as in header.js

Comment: It worked for me. I checked your code in my device with necessary imports.

Comment: I'm getting this error spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)